# A general question about a model's behaviour by uniformly selecting a finite number of inputs from an infinite input space.

Tags: uniform-convergence, uniform-distribution

I am conducting an assessment of a model to draw conclusions about its behaviour. I **uniformly** select 100 natural numbers as inputs. By feeding these 100 inputs to the model, I obtain 100 corresponding outputs, based on which I draw conclusions. One could argue that my conclusions are limited to these 100 inputs, and using different inputs from the infinite space of natural numbers might lead to different conclusions. However, in response, I argue that the **uniform** sampling approach ensures that regardless of the specific inputs chosen, the conclusions drawn regarding the model's performance remain consistent. Is my argument correct? If yes, I am seeking a few academic references on this topic.

Comment: There is no uniform distribution on $\mathbb{N}$ so you hardly could sample from it.

Comment: @Abstraction Is it because it is infinite? How about concentrating on a subspace of N, e.g. (1,1000000) and then selecting 100 inputs?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean by "conclusions remaining consistent". A bayesian update on observations would be correct - _regardless_ of the distribution. But, obviously, observing outputs for different inputs would lead to a different update (for example: let the model be $f(n)=0$ except for $f(42)=1$ - it should be obvious that having or not having $42$ in your sample affects your conclusions).